# VBA/Function/Formula, IF for multiple instances

Tags: vba, excel

say I have the following info:

[image]

and so on for all of A, is there a way to call multiple values in col A so I don't have to keep changing the formula in Col B. Essentially its IF A = _ & _ & _ & _  , I want it to change to _ & _ & _ & _ in col B.

thanks.

Comment: I have the following info.  (Well, you said to `say I have the following info`!!  But seriously, teylyn's suggestion of a lookup table is probably best, unless there are specific programmable rules regarding how each input value can be changed to the required output value.)

Comment: Hmmmm - If things get any more complicated than that, I suggest `Index/Match` over `VLookup()`, but it sounds like the Vlookup is right.

Comment: @BruceWayne - Why am I not surprised to see a comment from you, given the sample data being used in the question!  LOL

Comment: Thanks I'll probably use the vlookup table . Hopefully Bruce is the Cristian bale batman and  not one Ben affleck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a lookup table and use a lookup formula, for example

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$D$2:$E$100,2,FALSE)
```

Copy the formula down.

[image]